# Erro ao iniciar Projeto com React Native

Tags: android, linux, react-native

quando rodo o comando npx react-native init App
Acontece o seguinte erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei o que tá acontecendo, eu instalei tudo certo mas aparece este erro.

Comment: Obs: Fica travado neste numero 582, e não muda

Answer (score 1):

Isso são apenas mensagens de alerta, warning(aviso), mostrando que suas dependências estão deprecated(descontinuada)

execute na pasta raiz do seu projeto

```
npm outdated
```

para ver quais são as versões de suas dependências no arquivo package.json e quais são as versões latest(Mais recente)

ou simplismente execute na raiz do projeto

```
npm update
```